# HttpURLConnection.getReadTimeout() / HttpURLConnection.getConnectionTimeout() of -1

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, weblogic12c, connection-timeout

I'm trying to determine what the current readTimeout and connectionTimeout is on my Java HttpURLConnection object.  They are both returning a -1 with during the logging statements below:

```
    private InputStream getSomethingImportant(final String letterId, final String documentId,
            HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {

        InputStream pdfStream = null;

        final String url = this.getBaseURL() + "/letters/" + letterId + "/documents/" + documentId;

        connection = RequestResponseUtil.initializeRequest(url, "GET", this.getAuthenticationHeader(), true, MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE);

        LOG.info("ConnectionTimeout is: {}", connection.getConnectTimeout());
        LOG.info("ReadTimeout is: {}", connection.getReadTimeout());

        // ...other non-relevant code...
}

    public static HttpURLConnection initializeRequest(final String url, final String method,
            final String httpAuthHeader, final boolean multiPartFormData, final String responseType) {

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;

        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod(method);
            conn.setRequestProperty("X-Something-Authentication", httpAuthHeader);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", responseType);
            if (multiPartFormData) {
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=BOUNDARY");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
            }
            else {
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
            }
        }
        catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new CustomException(e);
        }
        catch (final IOException e) {
            throw new CustomException(e);
        }
        return conn;

    }
```

The JavaDocs on [getConnectTimeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getConnectTimeout--) and [getReadTimeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getReadTimeout--) both list 0 as a return option but say nothing about -1.  How should I interpret this?

Also, the url I am using is valid and I am returning an `InputStream` successfully.

Finally, I am using Oracle JDK 1.8.0_77. And, of note, when I actually print out the `conn` class that is being used at runtime it is `weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection` (I am using WebLogic 12.2).

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the minimal code to reproduce this. I just tried and got 0 for both timeout values using an Oracle jdk8.

Comment: Certainly; I have added more code context in the original question.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Apart from some additional settings, this looks like what I did. What do you get when you run the minimal example: https://gist.github.com/HaraldKi/428de48694d51faf218eb0bd81763f66, still twice -1? My jdk is 1.8.0_112 and the class I get out is sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.

Comment: I ran your example and the results were a little unexpected.  I still receive -1 for both the connectionTimeout and the readTimeout.  I also printed out the JDK version and receive `1.8.0_77`.  I receive `weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection` for the class.   Interestingly when I look at the JavaDocs for that [class (actually it's parent)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/javadocs/weblogic/net/http/HttpURLConnection.html#getConnectTimeout()), it only says that it `overrides the getReadTimeout method in class URLConnection`, but doesn't actually give the implementation fully.  :/

Comment: Well, if you've got a decompiler installed in your IDE, you could just have a look at the source and see what they do. Obviously they override it and use a different default.